# Hitting a 'local' sitecore 9 instance from another machine

Tags: deployment, iis

I have a 'local' style deployed Sitecore 9 development environment on a VM. I have to make a callout to invoke it from an external machine to test some functionality, however, I don't completely understand how to hit it from another machine.

What I understand is:

- On the local machine, hitting http://xp0.sc/sitecore loads the Sitecore Admin interface.
- On the local machine, Hitting http://xp0.sc/ loads the Sitecore live site.
- On the local machine, in the hosts file, Sitecore has crated xp0.sc to resolve to 127.0.0.1.

My questions are:

- However, hitting localhost/sitecore is not the same as hitting xp0.sc (why?)
- Say the machine name is myMachine. What URL should I be using to hit the Sitecore deployment from another machine?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not related to Sitecore. Is related to how to deploy a website

Comment: Here's why I believe this is sitecore specific. I don't understand why hitting localhost/sitecore on the local machine is different from hitting xp0.sc/sitecore on the local machine. If xp0.sc and localhost both represent 127.0.0.1 but point to different places, there must be something that the sitecore installation does to change IIS rules for xp0.sc to route to the appropriate folder. Without knowing what that is, I don't understand how to hit this instance from another machine. Another way to ask my question is, what does the Sitecore installation do to set up xp0.sc to point to sitecore?

Comment: Chances are that the binding on the website is mapping to the sitecore site you created. I agree with @SitecoreClimber that this is not a specific Sitecore behavior. Consider verifying that the IIS binding on the website is correct. I don't recommend opening up the firewall on your machine to allow for access like http://tarun713-PC/. If you want to do that though, the setup would be much like setting up Sitecore on a server.

Comment: Calma :-)   https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/29/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really not Sitecore specific but I'll answer this anyway.

Regarding your first question:
It's not the same since the web server running on your local machine routes the request to different sites depending on the url used in the request. In the case of Sitecore the web server is probably IIS. You can see and edit the configured sites in the IIS Manager. This allows you to run different sites (or multiple Sitecore instances) on the same machine using the same web server (think `xp1.sc`, `xp2.sc`, ...)

Regarding your second question:
This really depends on your network and who should be able to access it. In the easiest case you could access the site from another machine in the same local network via `http://myMachine` (given there are no firewall restrictions, etc.). In this case you would have to create an additional binding for your Sitecore IIS site (for example using the aforementioned IIS Manager).

Comment: Ah, I see now why everyone is saying it's not a Sitecore specific question. The piece I was missing was not understanding that the sitecore installation creates a second site, but the default website still exists in IIS and the default binding was pointed to that. By modifying my bindings I was able to default to the xp0.sc site. Thank you very much.